# jQuery, if statement swap images for sticky header, how to fade in picture?

Tags: jquery, fadein

I'm trying to find out how to fade in the image when it loads in the stick header. I tried

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).scroll(function () {
        if ($('section#skin_header').hasClass("scroll-to-fixed-fixed") && $('section#skin_header').find(".site_logo").length <= 0) {
            $(".site_logo").insertBefore($("nav.menu_box"));
            $("div.site_logo a img").attr("src", "/dnn/Portals/0/Images/FG/fglogo_sm.png").css("padding-top", "5px");
**$("div.site_logo a img").fadeIn("1000");**

        }
        else if ($('section#skin_header').hasClass("scroll-to-fixed-fixed") && $('section#skin_header').find(".site_logo").length > 0) {
            //do nothing
        }
        else {
            $('.site_logo').prependTo($("#skin_topLeft"));
            $("div.site_logo a img").attr("src", "/dnn/Portals/0/Images/FG/fglogo.png");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I would use CSS transitions instead. Small logo would have opacity of 0, except under `#skinheader.scroll-to-fixed-fixed` it would have opacity 1. Google will help you with the rest.